# Can I split mapIndexed work from kotlin collection in multiple threads?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm struggling a bit finding a solution for my app problem.
My app is generating chart with a million of points, and for this works I'm saving a string with all points separeted by an blank space on the room database.

That being said, i'm loading this String of points, splitting it nad using mapIndex to put a index on all of them, like this:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Float, Float>()
            signal.split(" ").mapIndexed { index, signal ->
                signal.toFloatOrNull()?.let { floatSignal ->
                    map[index.toFloat()] = floatSignal
                }
            }
```

With this code I can show all points on a Chart, but this operation mapIndexed is too slow when handling a million points (more than third seconds)
    My question is, there is a way split mapIndexed on multi-thread and then join the result? Sorry if it is a bit too hard to understand, i'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `chunked` and coroutines:

- `chunked` splits a list into parts
- `async` starts a new coroutine
- `awaitAll` waits for the coroutines to finish
- `flatten` combines the chunks of `Pairs` to one list
- `toMap` converts the list of pairs to a new `Map`

Be aware that `runBlocking` is only used as an example to create a coroutine scope.

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val chunkSize = 10000
    val map = signal.split(" ").chunked(chunkSize).mapIndexed { chunkIndex, chunk ->
        async {
            chunk.mapIndexedNotNull { index, signal ->
                signal.toFloatOrNull()?.let { floatSignal ->
                    (chunkIndex * chunkSize + index).toFloat() to floatSignal
                }
            }
        }
    }.awaitAll().flatten().toMap()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with running a `map` in parallel is that you might lose the order of the list. Here is an example of a `forEach` loop that'll be executed in parallel

```
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors


private fun getExecutor(threads: Int) = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)
private fun ExecutorService.run(runnables: List<() -> Unit>) {
    val jobs = runnables.map {
        submit(it)
    }
    jobs.forEach {
        it.get()
    }
}

private val _executorMap = mutableMapOf<Int, ExecutorService>()

fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachParallel(threads: Int = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), block: (T) -> Unit) {

    val executor = _executorMap.getOrPut(threads) { getExecutor(threads) }

    val list: List<() -> Unit> = (0 until size).map { i ->
        { block(get(i)) }
    }

    executor.run(list)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use RxJava

```
private val _executorMap = mutableMapOf<Int, Scheduler>()
private fun getScheduler(threads: Int) =
    _executorMap.getOrPut(threads) { Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)) }

fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachParallel(threads: Int = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), block: (T) -> Unit) {

    Flowable.fromIterable(this)
        .parallel(threads)
        .runOn(getScheduler(threads))
        .map(block)
        .sequential()
        .blockingSubscribe()
```

You can easily modifiy this 2 functions to keep track of the index if you realy need the order. You can use it like so:

```
 bigList.forEachParallel { 
        val result = someComputation(it)
        newList.add(result)
    }
```

Comment: Really thank you for your answer, I'll try it out later